# How do I write a code that takes user input to form an array, and from that array the user decides if we should find the smallest or largest value?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, while-loop, python-3.8

I need to create a code using loops to ask for user input on certain values.
Of those values I need to ask the user if they want me to find the smallest or largest number or just end the program. If the number -1000 is entered in the program the program ends. Basically how do I link my menu of options to a the actual actions per option.Here's what I have so far.

```
numbersEntered = []
lengthNumbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array:"))
print("Please enter your numbers individually:")

for x in range(lengthNumbers):
  data=int(input())
  numbersEntered.append(data)

def menu():
  print("[A] Smallest")
  print("[B] Largest")
  print("[C] Quit")
menu()
Options=float(input(f"Please select either option A,B,or C:"))

optionA = min(numbersEntered)
optionB = max(numbersEntered)
optionC = quit

while numbersEntered != C:
  if numbersEntered == A:
    print("The smallest number is:", min(numbersEntered))
  elif numbersEntered == B:
    print("The largest number is:", max(numbersEntered) )
  elif numbersEntered ==-1000:
    print("Quit")
```

I tried a while loop to connect the menu to said action but that did not work and idk why. I am a beginner programer so I'm very new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is incorrect. The correct way is to receive user input as a string and take action accordingly. The following is a working sample:

```py
numbersEntered = []
lengthNumbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array: "))
print("Please enter your numbers individually: ")

for x in range(lengthNumbers):
    data = int(input())
    if data == -1000:
        print("-1000 received, exiting")
        exit()
    numbersEntered.append(data)


def menu():
    print("[A] Smallest")
    print("[B] Largest")
    print("[C] Quit")


menu()

while True:
    option = input("Please select either option A,B,or C: ")
    if option == "A":
        print("The smallest number is:", min(numbersEntered))
    elif option == "B":
        print("The largest number is:", max(numbersEntered))
    elif option == "C":
        print("Quit")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much, also how do I get the program to quit after -1000

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but...

- The program doesn't really exit and bypass the remainder of the
  program if -1000 is entered.
- The input function is being converted to a float type instead of a
  string 'A', 'B', or 'C'.
- The while loop and underlying if statements have issues with the type
  and value being compared as well as not exiting if 'C' was entered.

Here is a pass at the fixed code... There are a lot of ways to solve this.  You were close so I added extra comments that I hope helps you with the flow and solving your next programming puzzle.

```
    numbersEntered = []

    # moved functions outside program flow
    def menu():
      print("[A] Smallest")
      print("[B] Largest")
      print("[C] Quit")

    #############################################
    # program logic starts here.  
    # You could put all this in a main() function
    #############################################
    while True:
       lengthNumbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array:"))
       print("Please enter your numbers individually:")
   
       for x in range(lengthNumbers):
          data=int(input())
          numbersEntered.append(data)
          if (data == -1000):
          break
       # exit loop if -1000 or all elements have been entered
       break


    # removed the OptionA, B, C and values as they aren't necessary

    # changed the while condition to skip if the user chose to exit in the 
    #  input section
    while numbersEntered[-1] != -1000:
       # moved the menu and input inside the while loop to repeat the menu
       menu()
       # changed input from float to str and convert to uppercase
       Options=str(input(f"Please select either option A,B,or C:")).upper()
       # compare to strings ('A', 'B', or 'C') vs value of A, B, or C
       if Options == 'A':
         print("The smallest number is:", min(numbersEntered))
       elif Options == 'B':
         print("The largest number is:", max(numbersEntered) )
         # check for 'C' input from user to break out of the while loop
       elif Options == 'C':
         break

    # move the exit/quit message to the end of the program
    print('Exited Program')
```

Comment: Thank you for your input it was very helpful. How can I also include the "length numbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array:"))
    print("Please enter your numbers individually:")" statement into the while loop like you did for the menu. When I tried it kept giving me errors.

Comment: The easiest way, to me, is to move the prompts for the lengthNumbers and the data array into an endless while loop.  Then add an extra break at the end to exit if -1000 is entered or all the array elements have been entered...  Updating the code